# How to make any view grow till I have pressed the button in android.( kotlin or java doesn't matter )?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Okay So, I want a feature in my android application where I want to enlarge the text with animation till I have pressed the button and as soon as I leave the button the text size should set to that appropriate length(like in fb messenger like button).

Right now my application is doing is that whenever I am pressing the button it is enlarging to only one particular size with animation. Its like the text is 20dp and after button press it is 30dp but I want it to enlarge as long as I have pressed the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use while loop and keep incrementing the text size by 10dp until it is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for answering but actually its not what I am asking. Haven't you seen the fb messenger like button functionality(How it grows till when it is pressed). I want that same exact functionality.